# Multiple delimiters in Scanner class of Java

Tags: java, delimiter, java.util.scanner

How do I use the `useDelimiter()` method of the `Scanner` class to use both the comma (,) and the new line character (\n) as delimiters?

I am parsing some text from a csv file.

Answer (score 28):

```
 Scanner s = new Scanner("hello, world \n hello world");
 s.useDelimiter(",|\\n");
 while(s.hasNext()){
          System.out.println(s.next());

 }
```

**Output**

```
hello
 world 
 hello world
```

- [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.util.regex.Pattern))

Answer (score 8):

How about `useDelimiter(",|\\n");`

Comment: It escapes the second \. Regex use \n to mean newline but so does Java so you write \\n which gets translated to \n for the regex.

Comment: Wonder why tomejuan didn't respond. Maybe "escapes", "regex", or the explanation about the second '\'.

Answer (score 2):

useDelimiter takes a regex pattern, so, it would be something like `",|\n"`

Answer (score 2):

My text file has entries like:

```
01-jan-2020,102
02-jan-2020,103
…
```

To read the two values from each row, it worked with the following, since each line end was having both `\r` and `\n` characters:

```
Scanner.useDelimiter(",|\\r\\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Jigar is absolutely correct.
But if it doesn't work, try `",|\\r"`

since most text files have \r\n instead of just \n

Answer (score 0):

Using Scan Delimiters for Excel files - don't overlook the RegEx thing.
In my case the excel file is delimitedby '|'.
I have been spending significant time to parse rows using scanner.useDelimiter("|"), and got back character by character. Replacing that with scanner.useDelimiter(**"\\|"**) has solved my issue!