# Crash course on useDelimiter with multiple delimiters?

Tags: java

How does the syntax work for Scanner useDelimiter? For multiple delimiters. Please explain | [] * etc. I am trying to read csv file so delimiters are , and \r\n. Please keep it simple because I just started coding. Also, if the delimiter is \r\n, do we need to use \\r\\n?

Edit : i searched around, there's no one source which explains specifically about useDelimiter. existing sources are only for specific use cases of useDelimiter. Looking for a guide to all the parameters.

Comment: You need to learn regular expressions.

Comment: If this is a CSV, why don't you use a dedicated library, like OpenCSV, for instance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple delimiters in Scanner class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898263/multiple-delimiters-in-scanner-class)